# Installing MDBootstrap (Vue version) in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm-install, laravel-5.7, mdbootstrap

I've been trying to set up a project in Laravel 5.7 and one of the requirements is that it need to have MDBootstrap and Vue.js. I tried following the [official guide for installing MDB Vue as a dependency](https://mdbootstrap.com/vue/5-min-quick-start/) using

`npm install --save mdbvue`

but now according to the guide, now I need to add 2 imports

```
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'mdbvue/build/css/mdb.css';
```

before importing the `app.vue` file but I'm not sure how to do this in the laravel (5.7) environment.

First, I can't find the location of the URLs of the imports above. And second, where am I suppose to place these imports?

If anyone has done this setup before, would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into the errors this is the solution I found.

The import are already done for you so that step can be skipped the missing step was to do `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2` with this everything worked fine for me